# Typescript noImplicitAny not causing an error

Tags: typescript

Using the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) with noImplicitAny turned on, I enter this code:

```
  async function a () {
    const b = JSON.parse('{"a":"x"}');
    console.log(b)
  }
```

If I hover over the "b" on the second line, I see that its type is inferred as `any`. However, there is no error. Am I misunderstanding what noImplicitAny is supposed to do or is this a bug?

Comment: [The `--noImplicitAny` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny) only generates warnings if the `any` type happens due to the compiler failing to infer anything better.  But [the `eval()` function's TS typing](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/84974838c7c770c63f3b4e2d0f6a37089e3f09a2/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L32) has a return type of `any`.  Hence it is not "implicitly" `any` (no more implicit than any other function return type) and there is no error.  Does that fully address your question (and I can write up an answer) or am I missing something?

Comment: Also note that unless you'd like to get into a discussion about why `eval()` is terrible, you might want to change your example to something with the same `any` issue.  Like `JSON.parse()`. [Example code here](https://tsplay.dev/N5eZdN).

Comment: Haha, if people want to complain about the contrived example they are welcome to do so. It was just the first way I thought of to get an any type. Sure, I would accept that answer. As a TS noob I didn't realize the "explicitness" of a variable was transitive like that. Thanks!

Comment: Okay I’ll write up an answer when I get a chance.  I’d still encourage you to change the example though.  Unless you are actively asking about `eval()`, it’s distracting, like asking about a mechanical problem with a car whose interior has large blood stains.

Comment: I'll change it because that made me laugh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The `--noImplicitAny` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny) produces warnings only in places where type inference *fails*, and it falls back or defaults to `any`.  For example, you get an implicit-`any` error when a function parameter cannot be [contextually typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing):

```
const f = (arg) => arg + 1; // error!
// ------> ~~~ implicit any
```

You also get such an error if an *auto-typed* variable (see [microsoft/TypeScript#11263](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/11263)) cannot be inferred by the compiler via control flow, such as if the variable is referenced in separate function scope:

```
let w; // error!
// >~ implicit any
w = 2;
function foo() { w } // implicit any
```

These are situations where the compiler says "I don't know what's going on here so I'll give it an `any` type".

---

On the other hand, if you call a function whose return type is `any`, you will get a value of type `any`.  This might be an "implicit" `any` in the sense that the caller of the function does not need to write out the return type, but it isn't due to a failure of type inference.  On the contrary, when a variable you assign that to is inferred as `any`, it's a success of type inference (just like `x` being a `number` in `const x = 1 + 2` indicates successful inference).  So there's no implicit-`any` error in these situations.

And since the [TypeScript library typings for `JSON.parse()`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/67673f324dd5f9398bb53fd16bf75efd155c32e7/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1059) looks like

```
interface JSON {
  parse(text: string, reviver?: (this: any, k: string, v: any) => any): any;
}
```

then

```
const b = JSON.parse('{"a":"x"}');
```

successfully infers `any` for the type of `b` and there is no compiler warning.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsI2ACgJQwDeAUDGTFJiMjAEYwC8MAUgMoDyAcgHQAOwAJxABTHAHJCAImCSAXJIAekgL5i8AblLkA9NopUatWdghhN5fRBDoANsO430Acxy08xZcWKUrNOIxgcQScCBgA+bAEnGABqGABGdRhdGGEBAXQBAEJiFIBaAsKIgD9SmFQAW14bVChUGmBTLzsaAHcklLSM7Ny9MOLyqpq6hqbWgIAmTUQUDCw4dHR8Ihhx5WS9Sura+pMwIA)